# Is instantiating a Queue using {a,b,c} possible in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, queue, icollection

Is it possible to do that in C#?

```
Queue<string> helperStrings = {"right", "left", "up", "down"};
```

or do I have to produce an array first for that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No you cannot initialize a queue in that way.

Anyway, you can do something like this:

```
var q = new Queue<string>( new[]{ "A", "B", "C" });
```

and this, obviously, means to pass through an array.

Comment: Okay … would have been too convenient to be true ;) Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this method require unboxing the strings? Would `new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" }` be better?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: First, strings are reference types. Only value types are boxed. Second, even if the array were of value type, the implicitly typed array creation operator infers the type. new[] { 1, 2, 3} is an array of unboxed ints, not an array of boxed ints!

Answer (score 12):

> Is it possible to do that in C#?

Unfortunately no.

The rule for collection initializers in C# is that the object must (1) implement IEnumerable, and (2) have an Add method.  The collection initializer

```
new C(q) { r, s, t }
```

is rewritten as

```
temp = new C(q);
temp.Add(r);
temp.Add(s);
temp.Add(t);
```

and then results in whatever is in temp.

`Queue<T>` implements IEnumerable but it does not have an Add method; it has an Enqueue method.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, that helps a lot in understanding the underlying mechanics.

Comment: So collection intializers are basically syntactic sugars, aren't they ?

Comment: @digEmAll: that is correct. The sweetness of the sugar here is twofold. First, that they are very compact. Second, that they turn what would have previously been a bunch of statements into an expression; that means you can use these in contexts where only an expression is valid, such as a field initializer or LINQ query.

Comment: oh you're right, I didn't think to the expression thing... thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

As `Queue<T>` does not implement an 'Add' method, you'll need to instantiate an `IEnumerable<string>` from which it can be initialized:

```
Queue<string> helperStrings 
    = new Queue<string>(new List<string>() { "right", "left", "up", "down" });
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer is: yes.
As [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4025219/6859121) said, it is actually the syntactic sugars, is the syntax analysis of the compiler, so it means that if the compiler can be made aware that Queue has an Add method, then it can "fool the compiler".
"Extension method" can made it:

```
public static class QueueHacky
{
    public static void Add<T>(this Queue<T> queue, T newItem)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(newItem);
    }
}
```

Then, this becomes legal:

```
Queue<string> helperStrings = new Queue<string> { "right", "left", "up", "down" };
```

**Warning: This is a Hacky solution, it just for solved this question, not recommend to use, it has code smell.**